# sudo apt-get update stops

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, aws

```
➜  ~ ssh -i ~/.ssh/yl-ec2.pem ubuntu@ec2-[...]ute.amazonaws.com -X

Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri Mar 10 13:39:32 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           115
  Usage of /:   31.7% of 7.74GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 12%               IP address for eth0: 172.31.12.34
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

36 packages can be updated.
17 updates are security updates.


Last login: Fri Mar 10 13:39:32 2017 from ip1f123456.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-34:~$ sudo apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0% [Connecting to eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (54.93.91.241)] [Connecti
```

The problem is what you see at the end of above session script. After `sudo apt-get update` an incomplete status line is printed and it stops there. Nothing happens.

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the last line is printed again.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then I can leave this process and return to the command line where I can proceed as usual it seems - f.x. `ls`, `cd`

---

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-34:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v '#'

deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

deb http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
```

---

```
> cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.31.0.2
search eu-central-1.compute.internal
```

---

```
> sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Is DNS resolving queries? Check `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I suppose it does. It is managed by AWS (cannot even configure it) and ping www.google.com works.

Comment: Firewall maybe..? `iptables -nvL` ?

Comment: see output - seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had this trouble, it was a security rule set in the IAM of AWS - that's where the firewalling and routing happens in AWS.

Comment: somebody of my team restricted the outbound rules

Comment: Aha! No wonder. One idea is to create your own security group so team members can't do that.